# Как добавить кнопки "WhatsApp" и "Позвонить" на обычном сайте, без CMS?

Tags: callback, whatsapp

Создаю обычный сайт про облицовочный камень http://saj-studio.com/golden/
Возникла проблема с 2-мя кнопками "WhatsApp" и "Позвонить" (они встроены в меню).
При нажатии на них - они не срабатывают! Почему?
К примеру на сайт конкурента http://ecostone.kg/ кнопки "WhatsApp" и "Позвонить" - работают ОТЛИЧНО.
Сам чужой сайт работает на Jumla. Возможно внутри этой CMS есть какой-то плагин для четкой их работы, я не знаю!
Посмотрел их коды, точно также как и у меня:

"WhatsApp" - `<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=996557342494" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
<li><i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Whats App</li>
</a>`

"Позвонить" - `<a href="tel:+996557342494">
<li><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Позвонить</li>
</a>`

Попробовал вставить новую ссылку https://wa.me/996557342494 - БЕЗТОЛКУ. Не работают ссылки! 
А на чужом сайте все отлично работает! Странно!
Думал может вообще ссылки не работают - но нет, внизу страницы есть ссылка на мой сайт и он работает!

Так в чем же проблема? Может какой-то особый *.js надо подключить???

У меня их 6 штук:

bootstrap.js, bootstrap.min.js, jquery.nicescroll.min.js, npm.js, wow.min.js, jquery.js

Поискал в Гугле, там везде описание про установку на Wordpress сайты.

Просьба посоветовать решение проблемы, с учетом работы этих кнопок на сайте и на смартфонах.

Консоль Хрома пишет что проблема в jquery.js:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А почему эта проблема возникла - непонятно!

Comment: Подключите JQuery и будет вам щасте =)

Comment: jquery.js уже подключен

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/iqmzTg3VGciIWA https://yadi.sk/i/bPF3Q8sSkSU6Hg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя все ссылки "#top_nav a" не работают из-за этого кода в конце страницы.
+ jquery.js надо подключать до bootstrap.js

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#top_nav").on("click","a", function (event) {
      //отменяем стандартную обработку нажатия по ссылке
      event.preventDefault();

      //забираем идентификатор бока с атрибута href
      var id  = $(this).attr('href'),

      //узнаем высоту от начала страницы до блока на который ссылается якорь
        top = $(id).offset().top;

      //анимируем переход на расстояние - top за 1500 мс
      $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 500);
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Вариант решения - повесить на ссылки в том меню (кроме tel и whatsapp) любой несуществующий класс, например MyClass и исправить

```
$("#top_nav a.MyClass").on("click", function (event) {
```

Comment: Я просто удалил этот скрипт! И подключенные файлы *.js удалил. Все отлично работает (просто я файлы *.js подключал в надежде на успех - а так сайт без них хорошо работал до этого)! Спасибо всем за посильную помощь!!!

Comment: Сайт в инете пока не работает, но его копия на локалке - отлично пашет! )